# Pyserial read from serial port and write to C program

Tags: python, c, subprocess, pyserial

I want to read some data using pyserial and then send the output to a C program using subprocess.

Here is my code (in progress):

```
from serial import Serial
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("./print",stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
ser = Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0",9600,timeout=2)
while True:
    if ser.inWaiting!=0:
        ser.read()
```

where `print` is the C program that simply prints the output (a stepping stone to what I actually want to do).

How do I get it so that I can write the result of `ser.read()` to the C program?

How do I interpret or use that input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write to [`stdin` of `Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.stdin). It's a file object.

```
process.stdin.write(ser.read())
```

Comment: how can i use that from the c program, then?